# Unable to Successfully Call Logic App From ADF Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have a V.2 ADF Pipeline, within which I have one copy activity which calls an Logic App. The Logic App returns JSON via an HTTP response.

When debugging the copy activity I am getting the error message:

> { "errorCode": "2200", "message":
>   "ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToReadHttpFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
>   remote server returned an error: (411) Length
>   Required.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The
>   remote server returned an error: (411) Length
>   Required.,Source=System,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target":
>   "Copy data1" }

Currently, in the "Additional Headers" box in the ADF Copy Activity settings I have the following:

> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Content-Length: 0

[image]

I have tried every variation of entering the two above parameters but the error remains.

I can successfully call the logic app using postman, passing only the Content-Type.

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exactly reproduce your issue:

[image]

The method is POST but you are sending nothing. You could write some fake data in the request body and it will be fine.

[image]

Success snapshot:

[image]

[image]